# writing a bitmap via remote desktop

Tags: c++, remote-desktop, bmp

After getting a sample from a frame within a video 
im writing a *.bmp file with the next c++ code :

```
RETVAL Cbmp::WriteBitmapToFile(char *pcFileName,
                               unsigned char  *pucBGRImg, 
                               unsigned short usWidth,
                               unsigned short usHeight)
{
FILE *fp;
BITMAPINFO bmi;
LONG lStride;
BITMAPFILEHEADER bfi = {0};
LARGE_INTEGER lgbeginning = {0};

if(!pcFileName || !pucBGRImg)
{
    return NULL_POINTER;
}

bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = ::GetDeviceCaps(::GetDC(NULL),BITSPIXEL);
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth  = usWidth;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight  = usHeight;

lStride = ( bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth * bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount / 8 + sizeof(DWORD) ) & ~sizeof(DWORD);
bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = lStride * bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight;

bfi.bfSize = sizeof(bfi) + sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
bfi.bfType = 0x4d42;        // 0x42 = "B" 0x4d = "M" 
bfi.bfOffBits = sizeof(bfi) + sizeof(BITMAPINFO);

fp = fopen(pcFileName, "wb");
if (!fp)
{
    return CANT_OPEN_PATH;
}
fwrite(&bfi, sizeof(bfi), 1, fp); 
fwrite(&bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO), 1, fp); 
fwrite(pucBGRImg, bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage,1, fp);
fclose(fp);

return SUCCESS;
} //end of WriteBitmapToFile
```

It all worked very good 
until some of the users found a bug,
that happens when they are using Microsoft remote desktop (mstsc).

when they hit the save bitmap button the file is saved corrupted
and then can not be viewd by my album screen

I noticed that it only happens while connecting from a win XP machine

I don't know if the problem is because of the way I'm writing the file
or if it is a Win XP bug or may by some settings I can change.

Comment: Is your software running on the host machine or the machine you are RDP'd into?

Comment: the machine i RDP'd into